# Glide.js not working?

Tags: jquery, glidejs

I'm baffled as to why my glide.js isn't functioning correctly?
It's almost as if the javascript is not doing anything.

I've followed the instructions to no avail from here:
https://github.com/jedrzejchalubek/Glide.js

Here is a jsfiddle. Any ideas?

```
<div class="slider">
   <ul class="slider__wrapper">
         <li class="slider__item"><img src="http://theme.co/media/x-slider-example-1.jpg"/></li>
         <li class="slider__item"><img src="http://theme.co/media/x-slider-example-2.jpg"/> </li>
   </ul>
</div>

 $(function() {
                $('nav#menu').mmenu({
                    offCanvas: {
                        position: "right"
                    }
                });

                  $('.slider').glide({
                            autoplay: 5000,
                            arrows: 'body',
                            navigation: 'body'
                  });

 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fq52fLx7/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fiddle isn't working because `$('nav#menu').mmenu...` causes a type error.

If you change your JavaScript to

```
 $(function() {

              $('.slider').glide({
                        autoplay: 5000,
                        arrows: 'body',
                        navigation: 'body'
              });

 });
```

things seem to work fine.

Comment: Reason the other function was in was because I use it in my version for another plugin however I have resolved the issue thanks to your help leading me to something else. Thanks!